# Get out degree indice for both vertices on the edge_list and out the indices on separate dataframe columns

Tags: r, igraph, social-networking

I used `degree()` function from `igraph` package to calculate out degree indices for both vertices on an edge for a small example edge list of 7 unique edges, and I am wondering how can I render those out degree indices into two separate columns for both vertices on the same unique edge, below is my example code:

```css
library(igraph)
g <- graph.formula(1-2-3-4, 2-5, 3-6, 2-4-7)
degs <- degree(g, mode = "out")
```

The desired output should look like this

```css
from to from_out to_out
1     2      1       4
2     3      4       3 
3     4      3       3 
2     5      4       1
3     6      3       1
2     4      4       3 
4     7      3       1
```

It will be really appreciated if someone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#turn graph to data.frame
DF <- as_data_frame(g)

#degs is a named vector
DF$from_out <- degs[as.character(DF$from)]
DF$to_out <- degs[as.character(DF$to)]
#  from to from_out to_out
#1    1  2        1      4
#2    2  3        4      3
#3    2  4        4      3
#4    2  5        4      1
#5    3  4        3      3
#6    3  6        3      1
#7    4  7        3      1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but I cannot reproduce your code, it appears that one cannot coerce class ‘"igraph"’ to a data.frame, and even if I used `as.data.frame(get.edgelist(igraph_obj))`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried in a clean session? What is your igraph version?

Comment: Hi, I am using the 1.2.4.2 version, and I found that there're some weird behaviors from my R if I use `as.data.frame(get.edgelist())` to convert a graph object into a dataframe, they your code won't work, it will produce all `NA` for the two new columns even after I launched a new R console and re-did the same thing again. But if I use a dataframe object as input, then your code works just fine. I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: I use the same version. Any reason why you are opposed to `igraph::as_data_frame`? `as.data.frame(get.edgelist(g))` produces different column names and you have to change my code accordingly.